# How to use "Material Components for Android" library

Tags: android, android-studio, material-components-android, material-components

I'm building my first app on android and I'd like to use "Material Components for Android" library to have more design options.

I read the [getting started](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) page carfully but it seems that my app doesn't inherit correctly.
``[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P53C.png) saying that it cannot recognize some inherited data...

 more expamples:
[cannot recognize label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVaUh.png) and the display is:
[display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efXgr.png)

Comment: In order to use multi-destiny vectors such as `ic_favourite_24dp`, you'll need to add them to your project. Check out this link to learn more on how to do so: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio

Comment: @Axiumin_ Thanks! but one more thing, I'm trying to use a different design as well (without icons) and it doesn't apply.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by different design?

Comment: I'll add an exapmle to the original post

Comment: You'll have to add a value for `@string/label` to your `strings.xml` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the icons that Material Components for Android provide, you'll need to import them into your project first. To do so, you can click this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio), but to fight off link rot, I've added the instructions below:

### To import icons from Vector Asset Studio:

1. In Android Studio, open an Android app project.
2. In the Project window, select the Android view. It should look like this:
   [image: Screenshot of Android Studio in Android View]
3. Right-click the **res** folder and select **New > Vector Asset**

Vector Asset Studio appears.
[image: Screenshot of Vector Asset Studio in Android Studio]

4. In Vector Asset Studio, select **Material Icon**.
5. In the Icon field, click the button.
6. The **Select Icon** dialog appears. You can filter which icons are visible by selecting an icon category from the list on the left or typing in the search field as shown here. [image: Screenshot of Vector Asset Studio where the user can filter for material icons]
7. Select a material icon and click **OK**. The icon appears in the **Vector Drawable Preview**.
8. Optionally change the resource name, size, opacity, and Right-To-Left mirroring setting. In your case, you'll want to make sure that the size is 24dp.
9. Click **Next**.
10. Optionally change the module and resource directory.
11. Click **Finish**.
12. Build the project.

Now, you'll be able to import the selected icon.

For the `app:startIconContentDescription` property, you'll have to add that yourself. The goal of the property is to make it easier for anyone using screen readers to understand the action of the text field ([source](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields)).